# jQuery curved path animation, Multiple paths

Tags: jquery

Good day,
I saw this plugin today (http://phrogz.net/SVG/animation_on_a_curve.html)
It's a great plugin from phrogz.net done by gavin kistner,
I was wondering if there is any way to use multiple curved paths in a page and apply them to one object so it continues it's journey in another path after the first one is finished.
It'll also be great if you could help me adding easing to it.

I'm trying to animate an airplane , here is the code that I use:

```
var curve = new CurveAnimator(
  [0,400], [670,410],
  [34,45], [250,-37]
);


var o = document.getElementById('plane');
o.style.position = 'absolute';

curve.animate(10, function(point,angle){
easing: "linear"
  o.style.left = point.x+"px";
  o.style.top  = point.y+"px";
  o.style.transform =
    o.style.webkitTransform =
    o.style.MozTransform =
    "rotate("+angle+"deg)";
    });
```